# JBoss not recognizing EJB jar inside of an EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, ejb, jboss6.x

I'm trying to deploy a simple test EAR containing and EJB project to JBoss AS 6.

I copy my EAR file to my JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy dir.  I can see my SUP.ear show up in the JBoss AS 6 Admin Console under **Enterprise Application (EAR)s**, but I do NOT see the EJB3 jar show up under **Embedded EJB3 JARs**.  I don't see the beans load in the JBoss console, and cannot access them.

I tried downloading the JBoss tutorials from www.manning.com/panda and built and deployed the chapter 1 example, and those beans load fine and I can access them from a client with no problems...

Here is the structure of my EAR file:

```
SUP.ear
|--META-INF
  |--application.xml
  |--jboss-app.xml
  |--MANIFEST.MF
|--SUP-ejb.jar
  |--com
    |--tomtresansky
      |--sup
        |--server
          |--ejb
            |--CalculatorBean.class
            |--CalculatorLocal.class
            |--CalculatorRemote.class
  |--META-INF
    |--MANIFEST.MF
```

Application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>SUP</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>SUP-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

jboss-app.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 1.4//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_4_0.dtd">
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>SUP:app=ejb3</loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

Both MANIFEST.MF files look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_24-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Classes are built from the following source files:

CalculatorBean.java:

```
package com.tomtresansky.sup.server.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class CalculatorBean implements CalculatorRemote, CalculatorLocal {
  @Override
  public int add(final int x, final int y) {
    return x + y;
  }

  @Override
  public int subtract(final int x, final int y) {
    return x - y;
  }
}
```

CalculatorLocal.java:

```
package com.tomtresansky.sup.server.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Local;

import com.tomtresansky.sup.shared.Calculator;

@Local
public interface CalculatorLocal extends Calculator {
}
```

CalculatorRemote.java:

```
package com.tomtresansky.sup.server.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import com.tomtresansky.sup.shared.Calculator;

@Remote
public interface CalculatorRemote extends Calculator {

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway this could be related to bad data in the /tmp directory?

Comment: I am having same problem could you share your test application with me.I have api jar,ejb and web module. I want to make ear package to intregate api jar and ejb module and have mentioned <ejbmodule> in application.xml but it is saying Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: my-ejb.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear vfs:///opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/my-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/

Comment: I solved this using maven ear plugin

Comment: (*psst* omg **please** don't flag a question as a "potential duplicate."  [You stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  Please only flag if it is a 100% exact dupe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found the answer...I wasn't including the `com.tomtresansky.sup.shared.Calculator` inferface in the SUP-ejb.jar.

It would have been nice if JBoss had provided some type of error message for a missing type...